# max number of clients reached celery

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, celery

I am using django with celery and redis.
I keep getting this error redis.exceptions:ResponseError max number of clients reached
I am using heroku and my redis backend has max connection of 400. I running 20 dynos for the main app and for celery I am running 5 dynos. How do I set the max number of connections? I've tried putting it in my celery.py like so:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'imdowntags.settings')

from django.conf import settings
app = Celery('imdowntags',
             broker=os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
             backend=os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
             include=['imdowntags.tasks'])

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.conf.update( CELERY_REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 20,)
```

also have tried putting

```
CELERY_REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS =20
```

inside of my settings.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably hitting a plan limit on the Redis server itself. If you are using the Heroku Redis addon, consult the plan descriptions: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis

You should expect a minimum of 1 connection for each dyno - for web dynos to queue stuff up, and the celery workers to pop stuff off. 20 web + 5 celery easily puts you over the for the free tier.

Comment: Hm... totally missed that detail, sorry about that. In any case, the key is figuring out the per-process (and by extension, per-dyno) connection count. E.g., if you are using gunicorn or uwsgi, you will have multiple processes (and thus multiple connection pools) per web dyno, so the number of connections may be adding up faster than expected.

Comment: Yeh this was the issue was the connection pools I set that config and it works now thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tyler - do you remember what specifically you set in the config that solved this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: @Tyler I am also facing a similar issue - can you please share what config change solved this problem? Thanks

Comment: If my memory serves correctly this answer was correct. I didn't change any config just had to upgrade the redis instance in heroku.